# How to load 10 item in Firebase whenever I click button

Tags: android, firebase

in my firebase database, I have lots of user to show on my Listview. I want my app load 10 item whenever click LoadButton.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple firebase query, which returns the first 10 users.

```
Query userQuery = dbRef.child("users").limitToFirst(10);
```

You can also limit it to the last 10  by changing `limitToFirst()` to `limitToLast()`

Comment: OK. first time limitToFirst(10) return 10 users, then I want click LoadButton to show user in position from 10 to 20.

Comment: You can load the first 100 users and add them to a List.Create an int which = 10, Whenever the button is pressed increase the value of the int by 10. Then loop through 10 items of the list and use them.